# How to group consecutive rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, grouping

I have a dataframe like below

| store_id | Rank | 3-Modulo-of-Rank | Modulo_Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | 1 | 1 | G1 |
| 123 | 2 | 2 | G2 |
| 324 | 3 | 0 | G3 |
| 241 | 4 | 1 | G1 |
| 111 | 5 | 2 | G2 |
| 124 | 6 | 0 | G3 |

This dataframe is sorted in order of rank.

**I would like to group every 3 rows of this data like below based on G1, G2 and G3**

| store_id | Rank | 3-Modulo-of-Rank | Modulo_Group | Key group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | 1 | 1 | G1 | K1 |
| 123 | 2 | 2 | G2 | K1 |
| 324 | 3 | 0 | G3 | K1 |
| 241 | 4 | 1 | G1 | K2 |
| 111 | 5 | 2 | G2 | K2 |
| 124 | 6 | 0 | G3 | K2 |
| -- | -- | - | - | K3 |

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby_cumcount`:

```
>>> df['Key group'] = 'K' + df.groupby('Modulo_Group').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   store_id  Rank  3-Modulo-of-Rank Modulo_Group Key group
0      2345     1                 1           G1        K1
1       123     2                 2           G2        K1
2       324     3                 0           G3        K1
3       241     4                 1           G1        K2
4       111     5                 2           G2        K2
5       124     6                 0           G3        K2
```